# Add custom fields wordpress post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am newbie for the wordpress plugin development

I need to create post type with below fields.

- Name
- Description
- Email
- Phone
- City -> Select box
- Gender -> Radio

I couldn't find the proper documentation for this. Could anyone help to add this fields in custom post type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For **Custom post type** you have two option

1. [Pragmatically](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)
2. [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

For **Custom field** you have also two option

1. [Pragmatically](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/#comment-3677)
2. [Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

This might help you. Thanks